# User authentication with Windows Active Directory

Tags: c#, angular, windows, authentication, active-directory

I write a webpage where I manage tasks. These tasks can be assigned to users. These users are loaded from a Windows Active Directory.

You have to log in to the webpage with the user to see the assigned tasks. I don't know how frontend, backend and active directory have to communicate with each other.

My idea was, that i enter the user data at the webpage and then the data is sent to the backend. Then it should be sent to the active directory and depending on the response i am logged in or get an error.

As frontend framework I use Angular. The backend is an ASP .net6 Core Web API.

The Windows Active Directory is located on a remote server. I only have reading permissions.

I have already tried a few things but unfortunately can't come up with a working solution.

I have already tried this solution but it does not really work for my problem.
https://gist.github.com/JaimeStill/539af65518091f7b8e6b9e003a493baa

Currently i am trying something with LDAP.

Here is a model how i thought the components would communicate with each other. [image: Model]

Comment: If this is for an application that only employees use from computers that are already logged into the AD account that they need to login to the site with, then use [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), so they don't even need to type in their credentials. As long as your site is in the Trusted Sites (in Internet Options in Windows) Edge and Chrome will automatically send the credentials.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think that your question is too broad and does not belongs here. Probably [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) will suit you better. Here, we review mainly written code, and we advise about best practices, design pattern usage, security issues, performance, correctness, unanticipated cases...